# VBA 400 error for range copy

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

Hi I am trying to create a macro that helps to adjust two time series. So I have to make the two time series have the same dates, by assuming that if there was no data for the date, the previous day's price is taken.

All of my code works except for the Range copy part. It doesn't paste anything, into the blank cells inserted. Does anyone know why this is so?  The line in question is the last Range line. I tried the .Copy(Destination) method also, but it didnt work too. Error handler says copy of range class failed.

```
Sub Adjustdate()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim n As Integer
Dim read As Double
Dim adju As Double
Dim entry As Long
Dim comp As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Value

n = 2
While comp <> lastrow
    entry = Cells(n, "A")
    comp = Cells(n, "T")
    read = Cells(n, "B")
    adju = Cells(n, "C")
    If (entry < comp) Then
        Cells(n, "A").Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Cells(n, "B").Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Cells(n, "C").Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Cells(n, "B") = read
        Cells(n, "C") = adju
        Cells(n, "A") = comp
    End If
    If (entry > comp) Then
        Cells(n, "T").Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Cells(n, "T") = entry
        Cells(n, "T").Interior.ColorIndex = 8
        Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH")).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Range(Cells((n + 1), "U"), Cells((n + 1), "AH")) = (Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH")))

    End If
    n = n + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

[Screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeIOj.png) 
Here's a screenshot of the code after the 400 error(it ran until the part where it inserted a new row.)

Comment: Is your data in ascending date order?  Or in descending date order?  (Maybe paste in a screenshot showing the first dozen rows, mainly so we can see what is in column A and column T.)

Comment: Your "copy" is copying the values from row `n` (which has just been set to empty cells by the previous line of code, which pushes the existing values down one row) to row `n + 1`.  You might be trying to copy row `n - 1` to row `n`.

Comment: maybe it's related to your issue: at `Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH")).Insert Shift:=xlDown` statement, cells at row `n` from columns U to AH are shifted down one row, so that after that statement completion `(Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH")))` points to empty cells and `Range(Cells((n + 1), "U"), Cells((n + 1), "AH")) = (Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH")))` statement would copy empty cells value into cells filled with values that were in that `n` row cells

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick replies @YowE3K @user3598756! Yes I believe you guys are correct and I was just confused from being frustrated at this. I also have another question however. Before trying to use Range = Range to copy, I was trying to use this function instead. `Range(Cells((n + 1), "U"), Cells((n + 1), "AH")).Copy [Destination:=(Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH")))] `  It did not work due to a 400 error. Please disregard the column numbers (A, T, U, AH) because they are inaccurate leftovers from multiple versions.(I commented out the second if function later)

Comment: `Range(Cells((n + 1), "U"), Cells((n + 1), "AH")).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH"))`, or even `Range(Cells((n + 1), "U"), Cells((n + 1), "AH")).Copy Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH"))`, should have worked.  Placing brackets (`(...)`) around the destination would have caused it to fail, because the destination would then no longer have been a `Range` object, and placing square brackets (`[...]`) around it wouldn't have helped either.

Comment: @YowE3K Ok I see thanks! I guess I will go read up on vba syntax

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot showing that your data is in descending date sequence, your problem was caused by the following two lines of code:

```
Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH")).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range(Cells((n + 1), "U"), Cells((n + 1), "AH")) = (Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH")))
```

The first line is inserting empty cells on row `n`.  The second line is then setting the values of cells on row `n + 1` (the cells which used to be on row `n` until you shifted them down) to be the values of the now empty cells on row `n`.

The correct code you needed was:

```
Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH")).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH")) = Range(Cells(n + 1, "U"), Cells(n + 1, "AH"))
```

---

You said in a comment that you had previously tried the following command:

```
Range(Cells((n + 1), "U"), Cells((n + 1), "AH")).Copy _
                                 [Destination:=(Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH")))]
```

(I added a line continuation character / line break simply to make it easier to read in this post.)

The reasons that didn't work are:

1. Square brackets ( `[...]` )in that context are just syntactically wrong.

So let's drop the square brackets off and pretend that you just said

```
Range(Cells((n + 1), "U"), Cells((n + 1), "AH")).Copy _
                                  Destination:=(Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH")))
```

2. The revised command is saying that the destination of the copy is going to be `(Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH")))`.  Although `Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH"))` is a valid range, the round brackets ( `(...)` ) around it are telling VBA to convert it from an object pointer to values.

   This means your destination would be a `Variant` array, which is not a valid "destination" for the `Range.Copy` method.

Dropping off those round brackets would have left you with the command

```
Range(Cells((n + 1), "U"), Cells((n + 1), "AH")).Copy _
                                  Destination:=Range(Cells(n, "U"), Cells(n, "AH"))
```

which would have been a valid command and done what you wanted.

Below is a screendump of a watch window showing the difference in variable types caused by placing round brackets around a range of `Range("A1:C1")`:

[image]

In summary ... although it is often considered a good idea to use brackets to enhance readability of code (e.g. in a complex formula), don't use brackets in VBA in places where they are not needed.